# Odoo, can't have two different siblings objects in the same view

Tags: odoo, odoo-10, siblings

I have a class named **detail_base**, and two other classes name **flight_detail** and **tour_detail**, the last two classes inherits from the first one, like this:

```py
class DetailBase(models.Model):
    _name = 'detail_base'
    fee = fields.Monetary('Fee')
    passenger = fields.Char('Passenger')

class FlightDetail(models.Model):
    _name = 'flight_detail'
    _inherits = 'detail_base'
    passport = fields.Char('Passport')

class TourDetail(models.Model):
    _name = 'tour_detail'
    _inherits = 'detail_base'
    age = fields.Integer('Tourist Age')
```

The problem is when I call the **flight_detail** and **tour_detail** in the same view, the browser can't handle the common attributes of both classes, If I assign 5 to **tour_detail**.*fee*, that number will be stored into **flight_detail**.*fee*.

It seems the problem is related to the attributes with the same name of different objects being *siblings*.

I will appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should either use `_inherit`

```py
class DetailBase(models.AbstractModel):
    _name = 'detail_base'
    fee = fields.Monetary('Fee')
    passenger = fields.Char('Passenger')

class FlightDetail(models.Model):
    _name = 'flight_detail'
    _inherit = 'detail_base'
    passport = fields.Char('Passport')

class TourDetail(models.Model):
    _name = 'tour_detail'
    _inherit = 'detail_base'
    age = fields.Integer('Tourist Age')
```

which should either create 3 database tables (`detail_base` as `Model`) or 2 database tables (`AbstractModel`).

Or you use `_inherits` like:

```py
class DetailBase(models.Model):
    _name = 'detail_base'
    fee = fields.Monetary('Fee')
    passenger = fields.Char('Passenger')

class FlightDetail(models.Model):
    _name = 'flight_detail'
    _inherits = {'detail_base': 'base_id'}
    passport = fields.Char('Passport')
    base_id = fields.Many2one('detail_base', required=True, ondelete='cascade')

class TourDetail(models.Model):
    _name = 'tour_detail'
    _inherit = {'detail_base': 'base_id'}
    age = fields.Integer('Tourist Age')
    base_id = fields.Many2one('detail_base', required=True, ondelete='cascade')
```

That will create 3 tables, and `fee` and `passenger` will be stored in `detail_base` table. Odoo will get it from there, because it is a sort of delegation inheritence.

Answer (score 0):

use inherit:

1- inherit without _name :

```py
 inherit = 'model.name' 

 new_field = fields...
```

this add this field to the `model.name`

2- inherit with _name:

```py
inherit = 'model.name'
_name = 'new.model'
```

here will create a new tabel in database with the same structure of model.name.

inherits: The delegation inheritance.

best example is `res.users` and `res.partners` user is a partener so when we create a `res.users` record we must create a `res.partener` that hold commun field like name, email, address ... and information related to users like passowrd and login are stored in `res.users` model and with type of inheritence you can access field of res.partener directly without having to create a related field. you can do `user_record.name` or `.email` or `.address` this will not be a problem.

i like to think of it as one2one relation.

```py
   _inherits = {model.name : many2one_field_id }
   _name = 'new.model'

  # m2o field should be required and ondelete = cascade
  many2one_field_id = fields.Many2one('model.name', string='Label', required=True, ondelete="cascade")
```

so when you create a record of new.model all field that are in `model.name` will be stored in `model.name`.

Comment: I can accept just one answer and yours it's very similar to the first one, If I could accept both I would do it, but I really appreciate your time.